# How to upload an image or any other file to online server like www.pythonanywhere.com or any other server in django ? via python scripts

Tags: python, django, image, upload, backend

## Models.py

```
from django.db import models


class Stock(models.Model):
    ticker = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    open = models.FloatField()
    close = models.FloatField()
    volume = models.IntegerField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=r'geeky.pythonanywhere.com/files', max_length=254,default="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRvj-aG0r4GBOQbne5fKQxoPdozZr81YZjrgM1etERa4RHWkvBOsw")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.ticker
```

here geeky is my username and pythonanywhere is the website on which i have my server account for running python script!

Answer (score 2):

PythonAnywhere dev here, try using the full absolute path in the `upload_to` argument:

```
image = models.ImageField(
    upload_to='/home/geeky/mysite/files',
    max_length=254,
    default='/home/geeky/mysite/files/default.png'
)
```

Also for the "default" argument (you might need to download that default image from wherever it is now, and upload it to PythonAnywhere)...